# hide/show a div in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, themes, conditional-content, design

How can I make my `<div id='banner'>` visible only in index.php and hide it on other pages like single.php in WordPress? My `div id='banner'` is located in my header and the header is displayed on all pages with `get_header();`

Comment: You can do it using css. There's always a specific class in the <body> for every page so you can target which selector that needs to be hidden or be visible.

Comment: i want wp to do it.

Comment: Index page is your homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting *index.php* specifically may not be the best option because this template file is used in many cases in WordPress. Eventually, all pages will fall back to using index.php if no other template file is associated with this page.

So instead of targeting *index.php*, get familiar with [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and try to use [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), whenever possible.

For example, if you want to display the banner only on archive pages you could do something like:

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) : ?>
    <div id="banner">
        <!-- Banner content goes here. -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Similarly, you can combine conditional tags:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
    <div id="banner">
        <!-- Banner content goes here. -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This way your code will be future-proof and compliant with WordPress Coding Standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide div on other page by using `is_home()` function like this

```
<?php
is_home(){ 
?>
   <div id="banner">
   </div>
<?php    
}
```

Whatever content you will type inside `is_home()` body (`portion comes under {}`) that content will be visible only in `homepage`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ for that if you want to do it using WordPress.

```
   if(is_page( 42 )) //This way it checks the `page id`
   // show banner
  else
   // hide banner
```